# How to limit the amount of images uploaded to the media library within post.php

Tags: media-library

Over time, the media gallery gets heavier and heavier. I noticed that in admin-ajax.php the wp brings 40 images in a single query, it is taking too long to render the images on the screen, sometimes more than 50 seconds.

How could you reduce these consultations to 10? And when scrolling, continue loading the other images every 10

I found this piece of code

```
add_filter ('ajax_query_attachments_args', function ($ query) { $ query ['number_posts'] = 10 return $ query; });
```

However, it only lists the first 10 images and I can't see the rest, it doesn't have a page or scroll.

There is already a whole job of optimizing the image

Print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnpgf.png

Comment: How big are your images and where are you hosting your site?  The media library is only loading thumbnails, so it should be relatively quick, there must be something else slowing down the process.

Comment: You are loading the thumbnails, the strange thing is that admin-ajax.php is pending for a while, I am not able to identify the problem. https://i.imgur.com/WHBcvyD.png

Comment: Check if somewhere in your theme functions file or a plugin inst de registering any of the built in WordPress file sizes, this happened on one of my clients sites and WP tried to load large files instead of thumbnails in media gallery. Also check if your server isnt blocking anything or any errors on the admin-ajax script caused by plugins. You can switch script debugging on in wp-config.php